# Как поставить картинку Uri на ImageView?

Tags: android, firebase, android-imageview, uri

Имееется Uri картинка полученная с сервера FireBase

```
Uri photoUrl = mUser.getPhotoUrl();
```

Нужно поставить её на ImageView

```
userPictureImageView.setImageDrawable(photo);
```

К сожелению, такой вариант не работает, картинка не обновляется

```
userPictureImageView.setImageURI(photoUrl);
```

искал в интернете но не нашёл(

Дайте ссылку на статью как это сделать или просто напишите код, пожалуйста.

Comment: Смотрите Pacasso, Glide и прочие вспомогательные библиотеки.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja или Fresco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с `Picasso`:

```
String url_to_image = newsPojoList.get(position).getUrlToImage();

try {
        Picasso.get()
                .load(url_to_image)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placehoder)
                .fit().centerCrop()
                .into(holder.image_news);
        if (url_to_image == null) {
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(R.drawable.placeholder_news)
                    .fit().centerCrop()
                    .into(holder.image_news);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Picasso.get()
                .load(R.drawable.no_product)
                .into(holder.image_news);
    }
```